# ActiveRecord creating new objects every time I load the index.erb

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm working on creating a simple wiki website using Sinatra and ActiveRecord. I'm having a problem where every time I try to load the index view for versions of a specific document, A new version is being created. I've taken a look at my routes and my Version model, but just can't seem to figure it out, although it is probably something glaring (I'm a beginner). Any help would be appreciated :)
Some of the relevant code:

VERSIONS_CONTROLLER.rb

```
# ===============
#    Versions
# ===============

# INDEX

get '/documents/:document_id/versions' do 
    @document = Document.find(params[:document_id])
    @versions = Version.where(["document_id = ?", params[:document_id]])
    erb :'versions/index'
end

# NEW
get '/documents/:id/versions/new' do 
    @authors = Author.all()
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
    erb :'versions/new'
end

# SHOW
get '/documents/:document_id/versions/:id' do 
    # @versions = Version.find(params[:document_id])
    @document=Document.find(params[:document_id])
    @version = Version.find(params[:id])
    erb :'versions/show'
end

# CREATE 
post '/documents/:document_id/versions' do 
    version = Version.new(params[:version])
    document.update(body: version.content)
    version.save
    redirect("/documents/#{ params[:document_id] }")
end

# REVERT

# The revert function is going to post to
# the create function above. It is going to 
# do this via a revert button under each 
# button on the versions/index.erb page.
# When pressed, the button will post a 
# /documents/:document_id/versions form
# with the params[:document_id][:version]
# set to equal those of the version under
# which the button is located
```

VERSIONS/INDEX.ERB

```
<div class="versions-index-wrapper">
    <div class="versions-index-header">
        <h1>
            Version history for document: <%= @document.title  %>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="versions-index-list">
            <% @versions.each do |version| %>
                <li>
                    <a href="/documents/<%= @document.id %>/versions/<%= version.id %>">
                    COMMIT: <%= version.blurb %><hr>
                    CREATED AT:<%= version.created_at %><hr>    BY:
                    <%= version.author.username %><hr>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <% end %> 
    </div>
</div>.
```

VERSIONS MODEL

```
class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :document
    belongs_to :author
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

    def self.latest
        self.order("created_at DESC")
    end

end
```

SCHEMA

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS comments CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS versions CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS documents CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS authors;

CREATE TABLE authors (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(255),
    last_name VARCHAR(255),
    username VARCHAR(255),
    points INTEGER,
    icon_url VARCHAR(255),
    github_url VARCHAR(255),
    twitter_url VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE documents (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    img_url VARCHAR(255),
    created_at TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP,
    author_id INTEGER,
    body TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE versions (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    blurb TEXT,
    content TEXT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP,
    document_id INTEGER references documents,
    author_id INTEGER references authors
);

CREATE TABLE comments (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP,
    version_id INTEGER references versions,
    author_id INTEGER references authors,
    content VARCHAR(512)
);
```

DOCUMENTS.rb

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :versions, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :authors, through: :versions
    after_initialize :init

    def init
        last_updated = Time.now.utc.iso8601.gsub('-', '').gsub(':', '')
         self.versions << Version.create({ 
             content: "version 1.0",
             blurb: "v1.0",
             author_id: Author.first.id
             })
    end

    def self.latest
        self.order("updated_at DESC")
    end

    def self.alphabetical
        self.order("title ASC")
    end

end
```

Comment: What do you mean by creating new objects? You mean it's creating new table entry? Which would be really weird as I don't see any create or save method being called inside index. And if you mean every time you visit */documents/:document_id/versions* path in browser then I think that's not something unexpected, you need to initialize object every time you make a request, right.

Comment: How do versions get created, a callback on `Document`?

Comment: The document object probably has the answer. Can you post it?

Comment: @JaimeBellmyer I've updated with the document.rb ..maybe it has something to do with my init class method in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `after_initialize` callback runs *every time* an ActiveRecord object is loaded into Rails. Since your app is loading the document on every request, your `init` method is being called every time, generating a new version.